# "Invalid URL" error for markdown file using Nuxt content module

Tags: javascript, vue.js, markdown, nuxt.js

I'm working on a Nuxt site using the built in [content](https://content.nuxtjs.org/writing) module, and running locally, everything works fine. However, when I attempt to build the site by running `nuxt generate`, I get a fatal error on the first markdown file that says `Invalid URL`. My markdown files are in the `/content/posts` directory, and the name of this one is structured `my-post-markdown-file` and named `my-post-markdown-file.md`. I've removed the problem file from the directory to see if it was just that particular file, but the process errors out on the next file, too. I'm following [this post](https://nuxtjs.org/blog/creating-blog-with-nuxt-content#lets-create-our-markdown-page) by Debbie O'Brien for using the content module, so it looks as if I have things created properly. Is there something else I'm missing?

**UPDATE:** I narrowed it down to sitemap generation. Following [this post](https://redfern.dev/articles/adding-a-sitemap-using-nuxt-content/), I have the following plugin defined for generating my routes:

```
export default async () => {
  const { $content } = require("@nuxt/content");
  const files = await $content({ deep: true }).only(["path"]).fetch();

  return files.map((file) => (file.path === "/index" ? "/" : file.path));
};
```

and then in my `nuxt.config.js`, I have the sitemap defined as

```
sitemap: {
    path: '/sitemap.xml',
    hostname: process.env.BASE_URL,
    gzip: true,
    routes() {
      return getRoutes();
    }
  }
```

My content directory structure is

```
content
   |  \
   |   posts
   |      \
   |       my-post-markdown-file1.md
   |       my-post-markdown-file2.md
   |       my-post-markdown-file3.md  
  about.md
```

And when I run `npm generate` it ends on this error

```
 TypeError [ERR_INVALID_URL]: Invalid URL: about
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using this configuration in `nuxt.config.js`, I was able to generate the sitemap for my Nuxt site using the content module:

```
sitemap: {
    hostname: 'https://my-website-url.com',
    gzip: true,
    routes: async () => {
      let routes = []
      const { $content } = require('@nuxt/content')
      let posts = await $content('posts').fetch()
      for (const post of posts) {
        routes.push(`blog/${post.slug}`)
      }
      return routes
    },
  },
```

I tested this both with a local build as well as deploying to Netlify.

One configuration I see that could be different is that the route you are returning may not be a valid endpoint. The return for the routes should be an array of valid relative URLs. Are you hosting your blog posts as "https://url.com/{post}"?

The above code is based on the [Nuxt Content integrations page](https://content.nuxtjs.org/integrations/#nuxtjssitemap).